# How can I update the value of one field to the most often used value of another field?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table similar to the following:

> ID     PAYEE     CATEGORY
>   001  Costco      Grocery
>   002  See's        Candy
>   003  Costco      Repair
>   005  Costco      Grocery
>   006  Costco
>   007  Costco
>   008  See's

Using MySQL withOUT the aid of a programming language, is there a query (nested or not) that would set the category of the three new rows to the most often used category for those payees?

For example, one of the Costco records (ID 003) has Repair as its category, whereas the other two Costco rows (ID 001 and ID 005) have Grocery as their category. Thus the desired result would be that the new Costco rows (ID 006 and ID 007) would be set to Grocery since that's the most often used category for that payee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure.. just change 'your_table' to the name of your table

```
UPDATE your_table
LEFT JOIN (SELECT payee, category 
             FROM
             (SELECT payee, category FROM your_table WHERE category != '' AND category IS NOT NULL GROUP BY payee, category ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS tbl2
             GROUP BY payee
           ) AS tbl2 USING (payee)
SET your_table.category = tbl2.category;
```

this will change the costco that is categorized as repair to 'grocery' as well.. if you dont want this, add:

```
  WHERE your_table.category IS NULL OR your_table.category = ''
```

to the very end of the query

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and for your solution. It definitely works. One question though. I have Category defaulted to an empty string as opposed to null. When I execute your code, all of the rightfully unchanged and empty Category values change to null. Is there a way around that? Thanks again.

Comment: Solved the null issue by putting the WHERE clause in parens and adding: AND tbl2.Category IS NOT NULL AND tbl2.Category != ''

Comment: sorry was out of the office yesterday, glad to here you solved it!

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
UPDATE test t,
  (SELECT category,
          payee,
          count(*)
   FROM test ORDER BY count(*) desc LIMIT 1) t1
SET t.category = t1.category
WHERE t.payee = t1.payee
  AND (t.category = ''
       OR t.category IS NULL)
```

Sqlfiddle at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed5b0/1/0

Answer (score 0):

I just couldn't figure out a way without repeating the creation of a derived table:

```
UPDATE t JOIN (
  SELECT s1.payee, s1.category FROM (
    SELECT payee, category, count(*) cat_count FROM t
    WHERE category IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY payee, category
  ) s1
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT payee, category, count(*) cat_count FROM t
    WHERE category IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY payee, category
  ) s2
  ON s1.payee = s2.payee AND s1.cat_count < s2.cat_count
  WHERE s2.cat_count IS NULL
) s
ON t.payee = s.payee
SET t.category = s.category
WHERE t.category IS NULL;
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e101/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql's multi-table update:

```
UPDATE mytable t
JOIN (SELECT payee, category
    FROM (SELECT payee, category
        FROM mytable
        GROUP BY 1, 2
        ORDER BY count(*) desc) x
    GROUP BY 1) y
    ON y.payee = t.payee
SET t.category = y.category
WHERE ifnull(t.category, '') = ''
```

There's a little bit of kung fu tucked away in there that makes it work: the outer group by returns the *first* row encountered for the group, which due to the ordering for the inner-most query will be the category with the highest count.

Comment: The issue is that you can't rely on a group by that is not making use of all the fields in the select statement. [Documentation says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html): `The server is free to choose any value from each group`. That means that any category will be fetched for a given payee, not necessarily the `first row encountered for the group`

Comment: @MostyMostacho yeah everybody keeps saying that, but in reality it works as i have said 100% of the time. I challenge you to create an example that doesn't work as I have said. In other words, my code would pass any test - because it will always work - which makes it good code by definition.