# Timetravel view in MySQL

Tags: mysql, view, greatest-n-per-group

I need to implement a timetravel view for prices in mysql.
The base price table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE product_price (
  product_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  date_valid TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  price DECIMAL(15,4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(product_id,date_valid)
);
```

The idea is that as time passes I select the right valid prices I have entered in advance.
Maybe the concept can be clearer later.
I  need to create a view so that for each product_id I get the latest price.
After a while I have found the SELECT that does what I need:

```
SELECT * FROM  (
  SELECT product_id,price FROM product_pric
    WHERE date_valid <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ORDER BY date_valid DESC
) xx GROUP BY product_id;
```

In order to create the needed view I understood I cannot use the subselect and need to create one or more intermediate views. Like this:

```
CREATE VIEW v_product_price_time AS
  SELECT product_id,price FROM product_pric
    WHERE date_valid <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ORDER BY date_valid DESC
;


CREATE VIEW v_product_price AS
  SELECT * FROM v_product_price_time GROUP BY product_id;
```

What I then get is not the sameas the original query I've written.
For example, I populate the table with just two rows:

```
INSERT INTO product_price (product_id,date_valid,price ) VALUES ( 1,'2013-01-01',41.40 );
INSERT INTO product_price (product_id,date_valid,price ) VALUES ( 1,'2013-01-03',42.0 );
```

The raw query returns the right data, (1,42.0), but querying the view doesn't. I always get (1,41.40).

Surely I am missing something as I don't know MySQL very well.
With another opensource RDBMS I have already done similar stuff, but now I need to cope with MySQL v5.5 and have no way to change it.
But the documentation and a few searches in the developers forums didn't lead me to a solution.
Any idea on how to solve this? TIA.

Comment: Your table primary key needs to change to PRIMARY KEY(product_id,date_valid DESC).  You'll get better performance over the long run.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc You are definitely right. But so far I am struggling to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query, regardless of the fact that is in a view or not.

```
SELECT p1.* FROM (
  SELECT * FROM product_price
  WHERE date_valid <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) p1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT product_id, date_valid FROM product_price
  WHERE date_valid <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) p2
ON p1.product_id = p2.product_id AND p1.date_valid < p2.date_valid
WHERE p2.date_valid IS NULL
```

The query creates 2 derived tables, which is not quite efficient and is also a bit harder to read. You can try creating another view for that:

```
CREATE VIEW product_price_past_dates AS (
  SELECT * FROM product_price
  WHERE date_valid <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

And then rewriting the original query as:

```
SELECT p1.* FROM product_price_past_dates p1
LEFT JOIN product_price_past_dates p2
ON p1.product_id = p2.product_id AND p1.date_valid < p2.date_valid
WHERE p2.date_valid IS NULL
```

Then you can create the view on the query that uses the previous view:

```
CREATE VIEW v_product_price_time AS (
  SELECT p1.* FROM product_price_past_dates p1
  LEFT JOIN product_price_past_dates p2
  ON p1.product_id = p2.product_id AND p1.date_valid < p2.date_valid
  WHERE p2.date_valid IS NULL
);
```

And finish with the simplest query:

```
SELECT * FROM v_product_price_time;
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83eb3/1).

**Why isn't the GROUP BY not working:** The error basically resides in an inappropriate use of a GROUP BY clause. The rule of thumb (although not 100% of the time true) would be to always use the same fields in the select as in the GROUP BY. Otherwise, MySQL will choose any value from the fields that are in the select and not in the GROUP BY.

For further information you should check the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html). I think it is pretty clear.

**Highly detailed explanation:**

```
SELECT * FROM  (
  SELECT product_id,price FROM product_pric
    WHERE date_valid <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ORDER BY date_valid DESC
) xx GROUP BY product_id;

0 syntactical errors
1 semantical error
1 warning
```

1. Semantical error: Selecting product_id and price and only grouping by product_id will result in an unpredictable price being returned for each price. You don't want to have an unpredictable value in your result set, otherwise, you wouldn't be selecting it. So you are 100% trusting in a value that you can't predict. That is indeed an error
2. Warning: You are ordering a result set and then getting rid of that order by wrapping it inside a GROUP BY. There is no sense in ordering something and then generating a different order for it. That slows performance.

Previous query should be fixed using one of the 2 basic greatest-n-per-group solutions. I've provided the shortest one which is the left join one.

```
CREATE VIEW v_product_price_time AS
  SELECT product_id,price FROM product_pric
    WHERE date_valid <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ORDER BY date_valid DESC
;

0 syntactical errors
0 semantical errors
0 warnings
```

Perfectly valid query. No comments at all.

```
CREATE VIEW v_product_price AS
  SELECT * FROM v_product_price_time GROUP BY product_id;

0 syntactical errors
1 semantical errors
0 warnings
```

1. Semantical error: Again, selecting product_id and price and only grouping by product_id. This will, the same as above, result in unpredictable results.

So, you're basically comparing 2 unpredictable results and expecting to be the same. The funny thing is that the fact of comparing 2 unpredictable results is more error prone than just 1 unpredictable result. So consider yourself lucky of having that increase of chance in finding this error in your code. The guy who asked this question: [How can I update the value of one field to the most often used value of another field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604822)

will discover a funny surprise when he finds out that the query was not working as he expected to be. Furthermore, 3 out of 4 answers in there are not properly grouping by correctly and returning unpredictable results. Not to mention Bohemian's comment in which he states his code `will always work`. So, congratulations Enzo, you've just divided by 0 :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your suggestion actually works, even if I don't get the difference between the "free query" and the one behind the view.

Comment: @Enzo As I said in my answer, it is basically unpredictable the result of an incorrect use of GROUP BY. Don't look at the logic in the query but rather in the GROUP BY. The query happens not to need a GROUP BY, so removing it would easily solve it :) Anyway, if you need a GROUP BY in the future you can follow the rule of thumb. That'll make it work properly. Btw, this is just a MySQL flexibility that is generating this complication... your query is NOT legal in ANSI SQL

Comment: your query works with just one product_id, which is not my case. Sorry if I have not been clear. That said, I have put all my (unsuccessful) results so far in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63dda/3) (thanks for letting me know they exist). I fear the second query, which does exactly what I want, cannot be translated into a semantically equivalent VIEW. The problem lies in the sorting. In the (sub)query the sorting is kept, in the VIEW it is not. What would then be the solution, if any? I need to create a view in order to "hide" a table in any subsequent query.

Comment: @Enzo Sample data makes things clearer. Always add enough to make the tests :) Check the answer again

Comment: I still don't get the point why my plain simple query works, while the correspondent set of views doesn't.

Comment: @Enzo It seems you haven't paid attention to the link I've provided to the MySQL documentation. If you read it you'll see this `The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.`. Basically, you're tossing a coin: the fact that you expect tails and you happen to get a tails is just coincidence. Remove the coincidence by writing proper SQL code. Find out more at the link in the answer.

Comment: In my query the sorting is "`ORDER by product_id,date_valid DESC`" and the reduction is "`GROUP BY product_id`". This is why "The problem lies in the sorting. In the (sub)query the sorting is kept, in the VIEW it is not". I wouldn't say I am gambling: I am asking what I need. While the result is random with the VIEWs as they are not evaluated in the same "context". Finally I  understood that my perfectly working query "cannot be translated into a semantically equivalent VIEW" in MySQL. While it's perfectly working in other SQL RDBMS. That said, I kept your solution as good. ;-)

Comment: @Enzo I've just added a highly detailed explanation of why the error DOES NOT reside in the ORDER BY but in the GROUP BY. The query, indeed CAN be translated into a view. But the query itself is wrong. Not syntactically but semantically. How other RDBMS solve this grouping by issue is up to the other RDBMS and you should read their documentation. MySQL does it in the way it is explained in the link I provided. And it is NOT the way you are expecting it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_price pp
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT product_id,MAX(date_valid) most_recent_date
  FROM product_price pp
  WHERE date_valid <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  GROUP BY product_id
) aux ON aux.product_id = pp.product_id
AND aux.most_recent_date = pp.date_valid
```

In the subquery you select the most recent valid date for each product_id along with the product_id. This will give you one row for each product_id (whose date is valid, that is equal or less than the current timestamp). Now that you have the product_id and the date_valid (your PK) you can safely join these rows back with the product_price table to get the rest of the data. This "trick" will not always work as a solution for selecting one row in a group in a subquery, but since you requirements are to get the most recent date for each product, you can take advantage of the MAX function.

You can put the subquery in a view if you want:

```
CREATE VIEW most_recent_product AS (
  SELECT product_id,MAX(date_valid) most_recent_date
  FROM product_price pp
  WHERE date_valid <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  GROUP BY product_id
)
```

And then:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_price pp
INNER JOIN most_recent_product aux ON aux.product_id = pp.product_id
AND aux.most_recent_date = pp.date_valid
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cd2a/1/0)